# Subselect sem condição WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, query

preciso efetuar uma listagem com sub select, e até consegui fazer ela utilizando uma condição, porém, preciso que ela ocorra sem condição
com a condição ficaria mais ou menos assim:

`SELECT *,(SELECT PLACA from veiculo WHERE ID_CARRO = "1654641106") as placa from ordem_os`

No caso eu tenho duas tabelas, uma nomeada "ordem_servico" e a outra "veiculo".[image: Tabela veiculo]

[image: Tabela OS]

e em minha aplicação preciso listar alguns dados da ordem de serviço, são eles, ID_OS, STATUS, PROBLEMA e a PLACA do veículo referente ao ID_CARRO

a listagem PHP fica mais ou menos assim

```
function listar( $link )
{
    $select = "SELECT * FROM ordem_os ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $select);
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if( !empty($linha) )
    {
        do
        {
        ?>
            <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                <td><?php echo $linha['ID_OS'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $linha['PLACA'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo substr($linha['PROBLEMA'], "0","40")."..." ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $linha['STATUS'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
         }while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) );
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div class="mensagem_nenhum_registro">
                    Ops!Nenhum registro encontrado
                    <br>
                    <img src="imagens/not_found_icon.png">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }            
}
```

?>

Como deveria ser meu query para pegar a placa referente ao "ID_CARRO" que é listado??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo um `join` entre as tabelas é possível, vai pegar o veiculo e "juntar" com as informações de ordem de serviço

```
Select
    *
from ordem_servico
    inner join veiculo on veiculo.id_carro = ordem_servico.id_carro
```

Você pode ver mais obre `inner join` [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Comment: Putz, nem lembrei dos joins kkk muito obrigado

Comment: Estamos aí para isso ;P, se resolveu não se esqueça de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/).